# Fat Free triggering a POST request

Tags: post, routes, fat-free-framework

In Fat Free it is possible to trigger a GET request by simply using route or reroute. But there are many situations in which the GET method is insecure and inappropriate for sending parameters. How can I trigger a post request to an URL and send parameters through POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `mock()`. I think it's what you're looking for.

https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree#mocking-http-requests

Comment: The only thing left unresolved is the fact that mock do not really trigger a submit to a page (script) but just do an http POST request (like curl). Navigation does not occur, so leaving unchanged the URL at the navigation bar. How can such a "submit" be triggered through fat-free-framework?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I say it's not possible. If you want to do something like that, use Javascript. PHP is serverside, so the request it does is only for itself, not the user.

Comment: That's correct. You're right. I was confused, and lastly I did't use mock as I realize that there were a esay solution for my problem. I was trying to pass a variable (by POST) from one script to another and returning back to the original script, the I just used a SESSION.variable and avoid passing and passing that variable among several http requests. Thanks.